# Json Encoding Issue in Database Connection

Tags: php, database, mysqli, json

I am having a slight problem when I try to connect to a db remotely and I would be really grateful for any tips. Here is the code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect($port, $username, $password, $database);
$sql = "SELECT name, date FROM `view_tickets`;";
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
    }
mysqli_close($result);
mysqli_close($con);
```

I want to result in json to be able to run this from a mobile app. At the moment nothing is displaying on the browser (I am running Xampp). I added some prints and can confirm that the connection is successful and the array is being filled properly. I managed to print it out using `print_r(array_values($resultArray));`

Is something wrong with my json?

I don't know if this helps but noticed that I am getting the following warning;

**Warning**: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/www/service.php on line 39

This corresponds to mysqli_close($result);

Any ideas?

Comment: mysqli_close($result); $result is not an connection object.. mysqli_close closes only mysqli connection objects (connections).. 
if you want to unset it to free memory just make unset($result);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is optimised version of your code.

Note that tempArray is remove (there is no need of it)..

mysqli_close($result) is replaced with unset($result) because $result is not a connection object. How ever unsetting is not required if this is the end of your code because after the end of the script php will unset all variables by it self..

```
$con=mysqli_connect($port, $username, $password, $database);
$sql = "SELECT name, date FROM `view_tickets`;";
$resultArray = array();

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        $resultArray[] = $row;
    }
}
unset($result);
mysqli_close($con);

// Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

Comment: Thank you Svetlio, that makes sense and the warning has gone away. But it still hasn't resolved the displaying issue. I get a blank screen with the current code. If I add a print_r at the end, the array is printed out. however why is the echo not working? Does that mean my json encoding is not properly working?

Answer (score 0):

The `mysqli_close` needs to connection given to close, but you're give the function your result from your Query!

Change it to

```
mysqli_close($con);
```

Then it should be working, if not just comment

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with the encoding of the character set. Databases can have different encoding, make sure it is utf8